# Content from Jar file

Tags: java, jar, java-font

Is it possible to create a custom font with a .ttf file that is inside a .jar file?
I've created a jar file with the following structure

```
Game.jar
├──Snake  
│  ├── lib  
│  |   └── game_over.ttf  
|  ├── src  
│  |   ├── GameFrame.class  
│  |   ├── GamePanel.class  
│  |   └── SnakeGame.class
```

I've tried to get the custom font by doing

```
Font GAMEOVER_FONT;
InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Snake/lib/game_over.ttf");

GAMEOVER_FONT = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is).deriveFont(200f);   
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
ge.registerFont(Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is));
g.setFont(GAMEOVER_FONT);
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it even possible to achieve what I'm trying?

Comment: André, maybe it is just a problem when you created the question, but the name of the font in your jar is `game_over.tff `. Please, note the typo, should be 'ttf'. Then use the code from @cello - basically, include `/` before `Snake` in you path, and get rid of the second `Font.createFont` method invocation, use `ge.registerFont(GAMEOVER_FONT)`, it should work properly,

Comment: ye it's a typo on the question the extension is right

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. And, the code of cello, does not work? It should be, indeed. Please, what problem has you got if you run it? The `null` `InputStream`?

Comment: I checked if (is == null) and it is when i run the jar I get ```java.io.IOException: Problem reading font data.```

Comment: Please, in your use case should be the same, but, can you try `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream()` instead of `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()`? Note the difference in `getClassLoader().`. In addition, please, place the font in your classes, your Java output directory, and try to read it from there, in order to check if there is an actual problem with the font or not.

Comment: Thats It! Write an answer so I can accept it as correct

Comment: That is great André, I am happy to see that it worked!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, although I think in your use case the result should be the same, try:

```java
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream()
```

Instead of:

```java
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()
```

Note the difference in `getClassLoader()`.

Perhaps there is some difference in the class loader hierarchy and it can provide you different outputs.

In addition, you can try placing the font in your classes, your Java output directory, and read it from there, in order to check if there is an actual problem with the font or not.

Comment: Does the InputStream interfere with Serialization? After that my Serialization stopped working

Comment: It should not André. Please, can you explain your new problem?

Comment: I think its too long to post on comments should I open another issue? but anyway the error i'm getting is ```java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection$JarURLInputStream```

Comment: As you wish André. If you think that the new problem is closely related with this one, modify the question, although I think it is preferable to create a new one, it is better to only post a _question_ per question in order to help people identify the actual problem that it is being resolved in the issue.

Comment: I have to go now, but will gladly review the new question early in the morning as well.

Comment: I openned an issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66501097/java-io-writeabortedexception-writing-aborted-issue/66501132#66501132 but i already solved it, the InputStream was declared as a variable class so I moved it inside the constructor

Comment: That is fine André, I am happy to see that you were able to solve the second issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

1: Use an absolute path to access the font-resource, like this:

```java
InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/Snake/lib/game_over.ttf");
```

Note the `/` before `Snake`.

If you don't use an absolute name, I think Java will search in the package of the class, and not at the root level of the Jar.

2: You are using the InputStream twice, as you actually call `Font.createFont(...)` twice. At least the second time, the input stream will either be closed or at the end, where nothing else can be read, so the second invocation will fail. Just use the loaded font for registering it:

```java
GAMEOVER_FONT = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is).deriveFont(200f);   
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
ge.registerFont(GAMEOVER_FONT); // <-- do not load 2nd time
g.setFont(GAMEOVER_FONT);
```

Comment: Still not working when I run it on the command line I get ```java.io.IOException: Problem reading font data.```

Comment: check if `is == null` or not. If it is `null`, then the resource cannot be found. If it is not null, then the tif-file is found, but there is some other issue then.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a second point related to the new exception

Comment: Still doesn't work and the InputStream is null