# java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; Issue

Tags: java, serialization, jar

Having problems saving the High Score achieved in my game with Serialization
The error I get when I run the jar in the command line is java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection$JarURLInputStream
I think this was working before don't know why it's having problems now

It might be because I have an InputStream, I'm also getting java.io.NotSerializableException: java.io.BufferedInputStream

```
InputStream is_game_over = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Snake/lib/font/game_over.ttf");
InputStream is_Premier = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Snake/lib/font/Premier2019-rPv9.ttf");

GamePanel() {
    try {
        GamePanel g = rescueGame("/temp/SnakeGameInformation.ser");
        HIGH_SCORE = g.HIGH_SCORE;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        
    ...
}

public void gameOver(Graphics g) {
    ...

    //Updates the High Score
    if(applesEaten > HIGH_SCORE) {  
        HIGH_SCORE = applesEaten;
        highScoreDisplay(g, true);
    } else {
        highScoreDisplay(g, false);
    }

    //Save the game information before closing
    try {
        saveGame("/temp/SnakeGameInformation.ser");
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

     ...
}

public void saveGame(String file) throws IOException {
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
    out.writeObject(this);
    out.close();
}

public GamePanel rescueGame(String file) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
    GamePanel g = (GamePanel)in.readObject();
    in.close();
    return g;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was that I was declaring

```
InputStream is_game_over = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Snake/lib/font/game_over.ttf");
InputStream is_Premier = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Snake/lib/font/Premier2019-rPv9.ttf");
```

On the class so it was going to be serialized which it can't so I just created the variable inside the constructor so it shouldn't have to be Serialized and solved it!

**The code should be like this**

```
GamePanel() {
    try {
        InputStream is_game_over = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Snake/lib/font/game_over.ttf");
        InputStream is_Premier = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Snake/lib/font/Premier2019-rPv9.ttf");
        GamePanel g = rescueGame("/temp/SnakeGameInformation.ser");
        HIGH_SCORE = g.HIGH_SCORE;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        
    ...
}

public void gameOver(Graphics g) {
    ...

    //Updates the High Score
    if(applesEaten > HIGH_SCORE) {  
        HIGH_SCORE = applesEaten;
        highScoreDisplay(g, true);
    } else {
        highScoreDisplay(g, false);
    }

    //Save the game information before closing
    try {
        saveGame("/temp/SnakeGameInformation.ser");
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

     ...
}

public void saveGame(String file) throws IOException {
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
    out.writeObject(this);
    out.close();
}

public GamePanel rescueGame(String file) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
    GamePanel g = (GamePanel)in.readObject();
    in.close();
    return g;
}
```

Comment: You should also close those streams.